# Me sale ese error de php en una clase: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'int' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)"

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, class, namespace

Tengo el siguiente codigo que es de una clase, y me tira ese error en la linea 11, en "protected int $noticia_id;", que no creo que sea ahi el error asi que no se que puede ser.
Intento ver en pantalla que se vea cada noticia con sus titulos, imagenes, descripcion, y me tira el error en el archivo de la clase (No en el index ni el el archivo de la vista). En otra pregunta que vi, vi que uno tenia algo similar que lo resolvió por unos problemas con los espacios, pero tambien lo intenté y no hubo caso.

```
<?php

namespace Proyecto\Modelos;

use Proyecto\Database\DBConexion;
use PDO;
use PDOException;

class Noticia
{
protected int $noticia_id;
protected int $usuario_fk;
protected string $fecha_publicacion;
protected string $titulo;
protected string $sinopsis;
protected string $texto;
protected ?string $imagen;
protected ?string $imagen_descripcion;

/**
 * Obtiene todas las noticias disponibles.
 *
 * @return self[]  La lista de noticias.
 */
public function todo(): array
{
    $db = (new DBConexion())->getConexion();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM noticias";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, self::class);

    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}

/**
 * Obtiene la noticia correspondiente al $id.
 *
 * @param int $id
 * @return self|null
 */
public function traerPorId(int $id): ?self
{
    $db = (new DBConexion())->getConexion();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM noticias
            WHERE noticia_id = ?";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);

    $stmt->execute([$id]);

    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, self::class);


    $noticia = $stmt->fetch();

    if(!$noticia) {
        return null;
    }

    return $noticia;
}

/**
 * Crea una noticia en la base de datos.
 *
 * @param array $data
 * @return void
 * @throws PDOException
 */
public function crear(array $data)
{
    $db = (new DBConexion())->getConexion();
    $query = "INSERT INTO noticias (usuario_fk, fecha_publicacion, titulo, sinopsis, texto, imagen, imagen_descripcion) 
            VALUES (:usuario_fk, :fecha_publicacion, :titulo, :sinopsis, :texto, :imagen, :imagen_descripcion)";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    
    $stmt->execute([
        'usuario_fk'            => $data['usuario_fk'],
        'fecha_publicacion'     => $data['fecha_publicacion'],
        'titulo'                => $data['titulo'],
        'sinopsis'              => $data['sinopsis'],
        'texto'                 => $data['texto'],
        'imagen'                => $data['imagen'],
        'imagen_descripcion'    => $data['imagen_descripcion'],
    ]);
}

/**
 * Actualiza la noticia.
 *
 * @param array $data
 * @return void
 * @throws PDOException
 */
public function editar(array $data): void
{
    $db = (new DBConexion())->getConexion();
    $query = "UPDATE noticias
            SET usuario_fk          = :usuario_fk,
                -- fecha_publicacion   = :fecha_publicacion,
                titulo              = :titulo,
                sinopsis            = :sinopsis,
                texto               = :texto,
                imagen              = :imagen,
                imagen_descripcion  = :imagen_descripcion
            WHERE noticia_id = :noticia_id"; // :D
    $db->prepare($query)->execute([
        'noticia_id'            => $this->getNoticiaId(),
        'usuario_fk'            => $data['usuario_fk'],
        'titulo'                => $data['titulo'],
        'sinopsis'              => $data['sinopsis'],
        'texto'                 => $data['texto'],
        'imagen'                => $data['imagen'],
        'imagen_descripcion'    => $data['imagen_descripcion'],
    ]);
}

/**
 * Elimina la noticia.
 *
 * @return void
 * @throws PDOException
 */
public function eliminar(): void
{
    $db = (new DBConexion())->getConexion();
    $query = "DELETE FROM noticias
            WHERE noticia_id = ?";
    $db->prepare($query)->execute([$this->getNoticiaId()]);

}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Setters & Getters
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getNoticiaId()
{
    return $this->noticia_id;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $noticia_id
 */
public function setNoticiaId($noticia_id): void
{
    $this->noticia_id = $noticia_id;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getTitulo()
{
    return $this->titulo;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $titulo
 */
public function setTitulo($titulo): void
{
    $this->titulo = $titulo;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getSinopsis()
{
    return $this->sinopsis;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $sinopsis
 */
public function setSinopsis($sinopsis): void
{
    $this->sinopsis = $sinopsis;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getTexto()
{
    return $this->texto;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $texto
 */
public function setTexto($texto): void
{
    $this->texto = $texto;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getImagen()
{
    return $this->imagen;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $imagen
 */
public function setImagen($imagen): void
{
    $this->imagen = $imagen;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getImagenDescripcion()
{
    return $this->imagen_descripcion;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $imagen_descripcion
 */
public function setImagenDescripcion($imagen_descripcion): void
{
    $this->imagen_descripcion = $imagen_descripcion;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getFechaPublicacion(): string
{
    return $this->fecha_publicacion;
}

/**
 * @param string $fecha_publicacion
 */
public function setFechaPublicacion(string $fecha_publicacion): void
{
    $this->fecha_publicacion = $fecha_publicacion;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getUsuarioFk(): int
{
    return $this->usuario_fk;
}

/**
 * @param int $usuario_fk
 */
public function setUsuarioFk(int $usuario_fk): void
{
    $this->usuario_fk = $usuario_fk;
}
```

}

Este es el archivo de la vista en donde cargo las noticias:

```
<?php

use DaVinci\Modelos\Noticia;

$noticias = (new Noticia())->todo();
?>
<section class="container">
    <div>
        <h1>Últimas Noticias</h1>
        <p class="lead">Qué está pasando.</p>
    </div>
<?php
foreach($noticias as $noticia):
?>
    <div class="card">
        <article class="noticias-item">
            <div class="noticias-item_content card-body">                   
                <a href="index.php?s=noticias-detalle&id=<?= $noticia->getNoticiaId();?>"><h2><?= e($noticia->getTitulo())?></h2></a>
                <p><?= e($noticia->getSinopsis());?></p>
            </div>
            <picture class="noticias-item_imagen">                  
                <source srcset="<?= 'imgs/big-' . e($noticia->getImagen());?>" media="all and (min-width: 46.875em)">
                <img src="imgs/<?= e($noticia->getImagen());?>" alt="<?= e($noticia->getImagenDescripcion());?>">
            </picture>
        </article>
    </div>
<?php
endforeach;
?>
</section>
```

Comment: en php < 7.4 es el int el que causa syntax error https://wiki.php.net/rfc/typed_properties_v2 en versiones anteriores al type lo podes implementar con setters y getters como en el primer ejemplo del rfc

Comment: @aloMalbarez Geniaal!! Era eso. Actualicé php a 7.4 y desapareció el error. Mil mil gracias. Me salvaste :D